# Why class "in" is not removed after the screen became bigger in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Just a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/tZXTv/

If I change the with of the screen to small, the menu became collapsed. This part `<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse"></nav>` receive this class `in`, but after resize again to large screen, this class `in` isn't removed, just if refresh the page.

Why important? If I want to style the collapsed menu I need some class of reference. I opened an issue in bootstrap github page.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13245

Someone know how to deal with a problem like this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved with this code (for bootstrap v3.1):

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
   if (window.innerWidth > 768) $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in')
})
```

customized from [#11653](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11653)

hope to see this kind of code in standard bootstrap soon, this is useful.